# FCTRL - Spoj, SIGSEGV

Tags: c

I'm gettin a runtime error, help rectify the problem. Could it be duo to the global declaratiob of count ??

http://ideone.com/6PMlrY

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count=0;

long long fact(long long num)
{
if(num==0)
return 1;
else
return (num*fact(num-1));
}

long long fzro(int abc)
{
    if(abc%10 == 0)
        {
            count++;
            fzro(abc/10);
        }
    return count;
}



int main(void) 
{
int lst,i;
unsigned long long ar[100000];
scanf("%lld",&lst);
for(i=0;i<lst;i++)
    {
    scanf("%lld", &ar[i]);
    printf("%lld \n", fzro(fact(ar[i])));
    }
}
```

Problem Set Link:
http://www.spoj.com/problems/FCTRL/

Comment: You assume you have a very large stack that can hold 100000 longs, and recurse 1000000000 times in the fact() function. That is a wrong assumption. And hopefully the input you read is no more than 100000 numbers too.

Answer (score 1):

You need not compute the factorial and then try to find its trailing zeroes.The reason you are getting runtime error is that you are trying to compute factorial values of very large numbers. For example 100! will have 600 digits which will be too large to handle leading to RE. Instead,You need to keep dividing the number by 5 and at each intermediate step add the value of the quotient that you obtain upon dividing n by 5.The final value that you obtain upon adding the sum will be your answer.

```
int ret = 0;
while ( N )
{
ret += N / 5;
N /= 5;
}
```

The value of ret is the number of trailing zeroes. Using the above idea try to get AC :)